# Static nested class has access to private constructor of outer class

Tags: java

It is [stated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) that:

> A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its outer
>   class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class. **In
>   effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that
>   has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.**

So how to explain this static nested class has access to private constructor of its enclosing class?

Comment: What is your confusion? Can you explain it with some code sample?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So how to explain this static nested class has access to private constructor of its enclosing class?

Because the scope and accessibility of any `private` member (field, constructor or method) is the complete body of its declaring class, including any nested classes.

From the [Java Language Specification section 6.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1):

> if the member or constructor is declared `private`, then access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.